# What's the decimal separator in a MySql INT field?

Tags: sql, mysql

Is this set somehow in a variable?

Is it possible to store decimal values in `INT` fields or does it have to be `FLOAT`?

Comma or point as a separator? Or does it even matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas aren't stored in the table...they're represented that way in whatever you're viewing the data with.

For decimal numbers, no you cannot use `INT`, it only accepts whole numbers, you likely want `DECIMAL` for this (So you don't get the odd 0.3999999999999999999999999999999 that can't be stored quite right in the float).

Answer (score 1):

The separator is not stored in the database.  You can apply separator using the [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function.

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.123456, 4);
        -> '12,332.1235'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.1,4);
        -> '12,332.1000'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.2,0);
        -> '12,332'
```

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

An INT field doesn't store precision. If you want to store fractions/decimals, then you need to choose a data type that will support them. The MySQL documentation is pretty good about what each data type provides you. I frequently go back to the MySQL documentation when I need a refresher on data types.